# Math.floor() and parseFloat() clash?

Tags: javascript, rounding, parsefloat

```
 $('#pm').val(Math.floor(parseFloat(pm*100/100)));
```

Full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
        function updatePay() {
            // Grab all the value just incase they're needed.
            var current_price = <?php echo json_encode($current_price); ?>;
            var pm = $('#pm').val();
            var gg = pm/current_price;

            // Set the new input values.
           $('#pm').val(Math.floor(parseFloat(pm*100/100)));
            $('#gg').val(gg);
        }

        $('#pm').keyup(updatePay);
        $('#gg').keyup(updatePay);

    </script>
```

When I use Math.floor it doesn't allow me to enter a second decimal.

I need my code to be able to allow a second decimal place to be filled in, how can I do this in Javascript?

Comment: *"When I use Math.floor it doesn't allow me to enter a second decimal."* Or indeed a first one. The whole purpose of `Math.floor` is to end up with an integral result.

Comment: `parseFloat(pm*100/100)` makes no sense. The purpose of `parseFloat` is to turn a string into a number, retaining a fractional portion if given. In your expression, the value resulting from `pm*100/100` will *already* be a number. You probably meant `parseFloat(pm)*100/100`, but that's effectively a no-op (it won't, for instance, limit the result to two decimal places).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#pm').val((Math.floor(parseFloat(pm)*100)/100).toFixed(2));
```

I think you want to round down and allow 2 decimal places,

so if the number is 3546.699433
parseFloat(pm)*100 = 354669.9433

math.floor(354669.9433) = 354669

354669/100 = 3546.69

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
        function updatePay() {
            // Grab all the value just incase they're needed.
            var current_price = <?php echo json_encode($current_price); ?>;
            var pm = $('#pm').val();
            var gg = pm/current_price;

            // Set the new input values.
            $('#pm').val((Math.floor(parseFloat(pm)*100)/100).toFixed(2));
            $('#gg').val(gg);
        }

        $('#pm').change(updatePay);
        $('#gg').chnage(updatePay);

    </script>
```

If you want something that gets updated on keyup, try something along these lines

Javascript:

```
   document.getElementById("num1").onkeyup = function(){
        var val = (Math.floor(parseFloat( document.getElementById("num1").value)*100)/100).toFixed(2);
        if(isNaN(val)){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "pm will appear here";
        }
        else if(val){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = val;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "pm will appear here";
        }


    }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <input type="button" id="myButton" value="click me"/>
    <span id="result"></span>
    <input type="text" id="num1" value="1.1111"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: That won't work because my other code is preventing it.  Updated OP with my whole function.

Comment: When I try to enter a 1 it only allows 1.01 and it prevents me from typing.  Check my new code.

Comment: $('#pm').val(pm); that works perfectly except for the fact if I try to enter 1.111 I want it to erase the hundreths place and only only two decimals.  You know?

Comment: @user2594145, did you try this?

Comment: Yes I did, it didn't work.  When I enter 1 it puts 1.00 and ONLY lets me edit the 2nd decimal.

Comment: @user2594145 so, is that the result that you are looking for?

Comment: Yes that's perfect but how can I use that in my function?

Comment: would using onchange function (instead of keyup) work for your code?http://jsfiddle.net/x98C5/4/

Comment: Yes just give me a couple of minutes

Comment: It works but it's buggy.  If I put 1.14 and then 1.15 it puts it back to 1.14 and doesn't update the new amount unless I click outside of the box.  Ehh, it's fine.  Thanks so much man!

Comment: @ user2594145 Will something like this better for you? http://jsfiddle.net/x98C5/5/

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve, but at a guess I suspect you want the values displayed in `pm` and `gg` to have two digits of fractional precision. If so:

```
function updatePay() {
    // Grab all the value just incase they're needed.
    var current_price = <?php echo json_encode($current_price); ?>;
    var pm = parseFloat($('#pm').val()); // Parse here
    var gg = pm/current_price;

    // Set the new input values.
    $('#pm').val(pm.toFixed(2));         // Round to two places and turn back into text
    $('#gg').val(gg.toFixed(2));         // " " " " " " " " "
}
```

---

Side note: You have this set as a `keyup` handler on the `gg` element, but you're always overwriting what the `gg` element has in it, without using the value in `gg` at all. If I were a user, I'd find that pretty irritating.

Comment: Only #pm needs to be exactly 2 decimals, I'll see if that works.  Thanks, T.J.

Comment: @user2594145: The thing is, `keyup` is probably not the right place for this, because when you update the value, you mess up where the cursor is in the `input`, so it's hard for the user to move in the field or change anything. You probably want `change`, or at least `keypress` with a delay on it.

Comment: Do you have an alternative?  That code didn't work..  It works but it gives me the same issue I commented on the other answer.

Comment: @user2594145: The code works fine, it's using the wrong handlers that's the problem. Here's a version using `keypress` with a timeout so at least you're not firing it when the user is trying to use the arrow keys: http://jsbin.com/ecihoz/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/ecihoz/1/edit)) But frankly, I think you need a different approach entirely. Changing the value of an input field while the user is trying to type in it is a bad idea and will frustrate users.

Comment: What can I do to fix that?  It is quite annoying.  On your code it does it too.

Comment: @user2594145: Not nearly as badly it doesn't. As I said, you need to change your whole approach. Don't try to update the field the user is typing in. Wait until they're done.

Comment: How can I do that is what I'm asking.  Can you show an example in the jsfiddle